# Why can't I set IFS for one call of printf

Tags: bash

Consider this line of code where deps contains a list of dependencies:

```
IFS=',' printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
```

I set `IFS` to be `,` for a single invocation of printf but strangely `printf` doesn't seem to respect `IFS` as it doesn't expand `deps` to a comma-separated list.

On the other hand, if I set IFS like so:

```
IFS=','
printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
```

printf correctly expands deps to a comma-separated list.

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this command line:

```
IFS=',' printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
```

`printf` does not expand `"${deps[*]}"`. The shell does the expansion. In fact, that's pretty well always true. Although `printf` happens to be a shell builtin, it doesn't do anything special to its arguments, and you would get exactly the same behaviour with an external `printf`.

The syntax

```
envvar=value program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

causes the shell to add `envvar=value` to the list of environment variables provided to `program`, and the strings `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` to be made into an argv list for `program`. Before all that happens, the shell does its normal expansions of various types, which will cause shell variables referenced in the `value` and the three arguments to be replaced with their values. But the environment variable setting `envvar=value` is not part of the shell's execution environment.

Equally,

```
FOO=World echo "Hello, $FOO"
```

will not use `FOO=World` when expanding `$FOO` in the argument to `echo`. `"Hello, $FOO"` is expanded by the shell in the shell's execution environment, and then passed to `echo` as an argument, and `FOO=World` is passed to `echo` as part of its environment.

Putting the variable setting in a separate command is completely different.

```
IFS=','; printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
```

first sets the value of `IFS` in the *shell's* environment, before the shell parses the `printf` command. When the shell then does its expansions in the arguments it will eventually pass to `printf`, it uses the value of `IFS` in order to expand the array `deps[*]`. In this case, `IFS` is *not* included in the environment variables passed to  `printf`, unless `IFS` has previously been exported.

The use of `IFS` with the `read` builtin may seem confusing, but it is entirely consistent with the above. In the command

```
IFS=, read A B C
```

`IFS=,` is passed as part of the list of environment variables to `read`. `read` the consumes a line of input, and consults the value of `IFS` in its environment in order to figure out how to split the input line into words.

In order to change `IFS` for the purposes of parameter expansion in an argument, the change must be made in the shell's environment, which is a global change. Since you rarely want to globally change the value of `IFS`, a common idiom is to change it within a subshell created with `()`:

```
( IFS=,; printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"; )
```

probably does what you want.

Comment: +1 Awesome explanation, I went with your suggestion of setting the IFS in a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just save it first, use it and reset it:

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=','
printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
IFS=$oldifs
```

Now for your command, you can do it on one line by putting a `;` between the commands:

```
IFS=','; printf "setup-x86.exe -q -p='%s'\n" "${deps[*]}"
```

You still need to save and restore `IFS` though.

The only place you can set `IFS` as a **one-shot** deal is in `while` loops. E.g:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read line; do
....
done
```

It is just applied within the while loop in that case.

Comment: The use of `IFS` by `read` has zip-all to do with it being in a `while` loop; it would work exactly the same way without the loop. (Of course, that would only read one line.)